# What is the best practice to use selector in Notification

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift 3, to register a notification, I can do the following ways:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.n1(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("123"), object: nil)
func n1(notification: Notification){
    print("123")
}


// #selector is more brief
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(n2), name: Notification.Name("456"), object: nil)
func n2(notification: Notification){
    print("456")
}
```

However, in Xcode 9.0 beta 2 (Swift 4.0), when I register a notification this way, the object method should have a prefix `@objc`, why? What is the best practice to use Notification?

`Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'n1(notification:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C`

```
//Add '@objc' to expose this instance method to Objective-C
@objc func n1(notification: Notification){
    print("123")
}

@objc func n2(notification: Notification){
    print("456")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not wrong.

As a matter of fact this is how apple explains you should be using selectors in Swift 4:

> In Objective-C, a selector is a type that refers to the name of an
>   Objective-C method. In Swift, Objective-C selectors are represented by
>   the Selector structure, and can be constructed using the #selector
>   expression. To create a selector for a method that can be called from
>   Objective-C, pass the name of the method, such as #selector(MyViewController.tappedButton(sender:)). To construct a selector for a property’s Objective-C getter or setter method, pass
>   the property name prefixed by the getter: or setter: label, such as #selector(getter: MyViewController.myButton).

Documentation link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID59).

And to answer your question about why, well selectors are actually a way to send messages between cocoa classes, not a swift feature. So they are actually based on Objective-C thus why you need to keep compatibility between them.

**Selectors:**

> A selector is the name used to select a method to execute for an
>   object, or the unique identifier that replaces the name when the
>   source code is compiled. A selector by itself doesn’t do anything. It
>   simply identifies a method. The only thing that makes the selector
>   method name different from a plain string is that the compiler makes
>   sure that selectors are unique. What makes a selector useful is that
>   (in conjunction with the runtime) it acts like a dynamic function
>   pointer that, for a given name, automatically points to the
>   implementation of a method appropriate for whichever class it’s used
>   with.

You can read more about selectors [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html).

But basically, they are just part of the "messaging" interface used by cocoa.